# Sending Large Query Results SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

My boss wants me to send a large SQL Server query result. The result is around 60 Million lines. Is there any advice on how to send this? File format? Compression? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Ask your boss... What format would they like it in? Can you compress it? What compression tool is okay to use? Is it going to a client and does it need to be sanitized... and how are you sharing the resulting archive? e-mail? ftp? file share...

Comment: He doesn't care about the format. He  just wants it viewable. Compression takes 1 hour or more. Im sorry if I am not giving over the best information. I was forced into becoming a DBA so my grasp of SQL Server is not complete.

Comment: You need more information, specifically what is the transport method and intended use at the destination.  As AIG commented it could be email, FTP, network file share.  Specific details are also important.  Is the FTP / File server on the local intranet or a wide area network?  Is the destination a third party software application or just an excel worksheet?

Comment: How is he gonna view it? Excel cannot open a spreadsheet with 60M rows. You can choose `Query > Result > Result to File... ` The file format is `rpt` but it's just a plain text file. You will need some specialized text editor (like Notepad++) to open the giant file though.

Comment: Joe C, I will try to get that information out of my boss ASAP and come back to this post. The biggest issue is that he doesn't know what he wants, he just tells me to find the best way....

Comment: I would limit the extract to 1000 records, so it wastes less of your and his time, At least he gets a sample that he can look at quickly

Answer (score 0):

What is the row size?

Typically when I need to export large amounts of data from SQL, I use BoostSSMS scripting templates. You could also use SSIS to generate the file, especially if this is an ETL process (since you can debug and step through the process). I find SSMS 'results to file' to be totally inadequate compared to BoostSSMS in terms of speed. My preferred format is tab delimited and single quote text identifiers.

If you're sending the data somewhere, it's probably best to compress it (which will drastically reduce the file size). Which method to use is going to depend on your target and their requirements but I've never had any problems with plain old ZIP compression.

Edit - your boss says he just wants to view it. Ask him what exactly he's looking for (whether that's some specific combination of values, or doing analysis on the data). The reason that's important is because I can guarantee he isn't looking at this data line-by-line for 60 million rows. If he's looking for something specific, filter your query down using those conditions. If he's doing analysis on it, do the aggregation in your SQL and give him the results.

Answer (score 0):

My tested solution: run the query and get grid result, then right click the result or the bottom space and choose ‘Save Results As’, choose a file format like tab delimited text file or CSV file.  Compressed the file with a tool like Zip.